# How to use Trigger Function to control div being shown or hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to know how to use trigger function in this code

```
    function showHusbandFun(){
    var mStatus = document.getElementById('marital_status').value;
    if(mStatus == 'Married'){
       $("#spousehide").show(); 
        $("#spousehideOther").show();       
    }else{       
       $("#spouse_name").val("");
       $("#spouse_nationality").val("");
       $("#spouse_place_of_birth").val("");
       $("#spouse_country_of_birth").val("");
       $("#spousehide").hide();
       $("#spousehideOther").hide();
    }
}
```

This is my Select Element Which Control Hidden Divs

```
<select class="form-control-input" name="marital_status" id="marital_status" onclick="removeError(this.id);" onchange="removeError(this.id); showHusbandFun();">
                    <option selected="selected" value="">Select Marital Status</option>
                    <option value="Single" <?php if($marital == 'Single'){ echo "selected";}?>> Single</option>
                    <option value="Married" <?php if($marital == 'Married'){ echo "selected";}?>> Married</option>
                    <option value="Divorced" <?php if($marital == 'Divorced'){ echo "selected";}?>> Divorced</option>
                     <option value="Widow" <?php if($marital == 'Widow'){ echo "selected";}?>> Widow</option>

                    <option value="Deceased" <?php if($marital == 'Deceased'){ echo "selected";}?>> Deceased</option>
                    <option value="Unspecific" <?php if($marital == 'Unspecific'){ echo "selected";}?>> Unspecific</option>                 
                    <option value="Child" <?php if($marital == 'Child'){ echo "selected";}?>> Child</option>
                </select>
```

i want to use trigger function in this to control the show/hide elements.
But Issue is When page Loads, I want to Show Hidden Divs When Marrital Status is Married.

Comment: You are calling function on EVENT i.e. onChange hence it will work only when the SELECT has been changed. To make it work for the first time, run your showHusbandFun() on page load as well.

Comment: @TusharShukla : Hi Mate, I am not able to understand it. Can You help me with the code.

Comment: Have you understood this now?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not calling the function on page load and you are expecting it to work on page load. Currently the function `showHusbandFun()` is triggered when there is a change done on the `SELECT`. You can do it like:

```
$(function() {
  // This is document ready function
  // This will trigger as soon as the document ready event fires
  showHusbandFun();
});
```

This way a one time change at the time of page load will be applied and then will work as expected on change of your `SELECT` as well.

Let me know in case of any confusion.

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the CHECK MARK icon if it solves your query.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery provides a callback to which notifies when the page loads.
All you have to do is invoke the function in the 'document.ready' callback.
The below snippet should handle your case:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 function removeError(id){
 //console.log(id);
}

function showHusbandFun(){
    var mStatus = document.getElementById('marital_status').value;
    if(mStatus == 'Married'){
       $("#spousehide").show(); 
        $("#spousehideOther").show();       
    }else{       
       $("#spouse_name").val("");
       $("#spouse_nationality").val("");
       $("#spouse_place_of_birth").val("");
       $("#spouse_country_of_birth").val("");
       $("#spousehide").hide();
       $("#spousehideOther").hide();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  showHusbandFun();
});
</script>

<select class="form-control-input" name="marital_status" id="marital_status" onclick="removeError(this.id);" onchange="removeError(this.id); showHusbandFun();">
                    <optio selected value="">Select Marital Status</option>
                    <option value="Single"> Single </option>
                    <option  value="Married"> Married </option>
                    <option value="Divorced"> Divorced </option>
                     <option value="Widow"> Widow </option>

                    <option value="Deceased"> Deceased </option>
                    <option value="Unspecific"> Unspecific</option>                  
                    <option value="Child"> Child </option>
</select>

<div id="spousehide">Spouse</div>
<div id="spousehideOther">Spouse other</div>
<div id="spouse_name">Spouse Name</div>
<div id="spouse_place_of_birth">Spouse Nationality</div>
<div id="spouse_country_of_birth">Spouse Country of Birth</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `showHusbandFun()` outside of your `onchange()` inside of your script. Then it will be called on page load and you should get the results you expect.

Comment: Hello Mate, Can You Help with the code, i am not able to get it.

Comment: If you put `showHusbandFun()` at the very bottom of the script it should work :)